# Local variable is not defined within the function, but it is defined outside and above it

Tags: python-3.7

I havent ran into this before, if i take the code out of triangle() and put it under the while loop everything works great. if I add triangle(input_argument) it then runs but never exits the while loop even if you type a string.

...

def main():

```
# Defining initial conditions.
input_argument = input("Enter a number or done: ")
triangle_list = []

def triangle():
    input_argument = int(input_argument)
    triangle_number = (input_argument*(input_argument+1)//2)
    triangle_list.append(triangle_number)
    print("Your number of", input_argument, "has a triangle number of",
          str(triangle_number) + ".")
    input_argument = input("Enter a new number or done: ")

# Test function for input between int or anything else.
def num_test():
    try:
        int(input_argument)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

while num_test() is True:
    triangle()
    num_test()


print(triangle_list)
```

main()
...

EDIT:

```
def num_test(input_argument):
    try:
        int(input_argument)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def triangle(input_argument, triangle_list):
    input_argument = int(input_argument)
    triangle_number = (input_argument*(input_argument+1)//2)
    triangle_list.append(triangle_number)
    print("Your number of", input_argument, "has a triangle number of",
            str(triangle_number) + ".")
    input_argument = input("Enter a new number or done: ")
    return 

def main():

    input_argument = input("Enter a number or done: ")
    triangle_list = []

    while num_test(input_argument) is True:
        triangle(input_argument, triangle_list)
        num_test(input_argument)


    print(triangle_list)
main()
```

Comment: Protip: don't rely on global vars. If your `triangle` function works on vars that are not declared inside of it, pass them in. `def triangle(input, list): ......` (referencing those arguments, not the global variables) and then call it appropriately, too, using `triangle(input_argument, triangle_list)`

Comment: Ok Ive edited it like you said but now my while loop never breaks?

Comment: not according to your post, which is still the original code?

Comment: Why are you calling `num_test()` inside your `while(num_test)` loop?

Comment: I left the original up top and edited like how i thought you said to. I thought I had to call the num_test in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of elementary mistakes here, so let's run through a fixed version instead:

```py
def get_input():
    try:
        value = input('Enter a number or done:')
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return False

def triangle(input, list):
    triangle_number = (input*(input+1)//2)
    list.append(triangle_number)
    print(f"Your number of {input} has a triangle number of {str(triangle_number)}.")

def main():
    triangle_list = []

    while True:
        value = get_input()
        if value is False:
            break
        triangle(value, triangle_list)

    print(triangle_list)

main()
```

Let's start with `main`, which is conceptually really simple:

1. we set up a list,
2. then we fill it,
3. then we print it.

How do we fill it? We loop our input aggregation:

1. get a value from the user. That'll either be a number, or `False`
2. if it's False, immediately stop looping.
3. if it's not, call our triangle function, with the current value, and the list of previous values

How do we get a value from the user? We use `input()`, and then try to return the int-cast version of that input. If that fails, we know the input was number a number, but otherwise we just return a number: exactly what we needed.

What does our triangle function do? It takes the current value and list of previous values, calculates some number, adds the current value to the list of previous values, prints, and exits.

Also not the Python 3 version of formatted strings: don't use string concatenation if you want a string with values-from-variables (or even values-from-other-code-calls). Use formatted strings, they're great.

Comment: remember to upvote useful answers, and accept the answer that helps solve your problem. Without that, SO wouldn't be the useful website it is.